# Python 3 urllib Discord vs Slack Bot

Tags: python, discord, webhooks, slack-api

I have this simple python script which is supposed to send me a message on Slack, and it works fine.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import json

# Provide the webhook URL that slack generated
slack_webhook_url = 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/josadfs/nfonwnfoawf/abcdsads'

# Post the message to the slack webhook
message = {
    "text": "Hello world"
}

req = Request(slack_webhook_url, json.dumps(message).encode('utf-8'))

response = urlopen(req)
response.read()
```

I have another script the does the same thing, but for discord.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import json

# Provide the webhook URL that slack generated
slack_webhook_url = 'https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/252534154132/knskdnvoangoe0940507230'

# Post the message to the slack webhook
message = {
    "content": "Hello world"
}

req = Request(slack_webhook_url, json.dumps(message).encode('utf-8'))

response = urlopen(req)
response.read()
```

For some reason, this gives me a `HTTP Error 403: Forbidden` error.

The `curl` commands both work, so it's not an API key issue. The discord script works when using the requests module, though.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

import json
import requests

# Provide the webhook URL that Discord generated
discord_webhook_url = 'https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/252534154132/knskdnvoangoe0940507230'

# Post the message to the Discord webhook
data = {
    "content": "Hello world"
}
requests.post(discord_webhook_url, data=data)
```

Is there something wrong with my urllib implementation? Can the discord request be sent using urllib?

Comment: Why does your title say `Telegram` when it's not mentioned in the question?

Comment: Sorry! That was a typo. I also tried it with telegram, though and it had a similar problem to discord.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that Discord blocks the requests from the default user-agent of Python's urllib. I was able to successfully execute the code by specifying User-Agent and Content-Type using Request.add_header(). I tested the below code and it worked for me.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import json

# Provide the webhook URL that slack generated
slack_webhook_url = '<redacted>'

# Post the message to the slack webhook
message = {
    "content": "Hello world"
}

req = Request(slack_webhook_url, json.dumps(message).encode('utf-8'))

#specifying headers for the request, discord appears to block the  default urllib user-agent
req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
req.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11')

response = urlopen(req)
response.read()
```

Comment: An answer after forever! Thank you!